# tcsd has failed, what next?

Tags: fedora

After upgrading my Fedora OS, I found two services managed by `systemd` failing to start. One of which is `tcsd`. As I know it from Linux Man page, `tcsd` is a daemon that manages Trusted Computing resources. How do I go about troubleshooting the problem?

Is it wise to do:

```
# systemctl disable tcsd.service
```

and move on?

Comment: What does `systemctl status tcsd.service` tell you? It should give tke last lines from the log for the service. Everything up to date, BTW? Looked at bugzilla for any reported problems?

Comment: @vonbrand, thanks for the concern. I have moved on to Fedora 18 and the issue does not appear anymore. Now it just show that it is loaded but inactive. Shall close this question after you see my message.

Comment: Have you tried starting it? You wanted to use it, didn't you?

Comment: No, actually I don't think I need it and have no idea what it is for. But it is loaded by default. I post this question because I saw the failed status in my previous installation.